# Get a value from Json Object in java

Tags: java, json

```
"response": {
"code": "0",
"comment": "",
"log_id": "51c55b29-e1e7-4855-9fd8-d920eff82fbe"},
"styles": {
"style": [{
  "style_id": "3745150",
  "style_name": "Westy",
  "style_number": "WEST01M1",
  "style_identifier": "WEST01M1||",
  "style_description": "",
  "made_to_order": "True",
  "division": "MEN'S SHOES",
  "division_code": "M1",
  "style_country_origin": "",
  "measurements": "",
  "fabrication": "",
  "fabrication_code": "",
  "silhouette": "",
  "silhouette_code": "",
  "source_of_materials": "",
  "heel_height": "",
  "contains_fur": "",
  "best_seller": "False",
  "minimum": "12",

  "categories": [  
    {
        "category_parent": "Men's",
        "subcategories": [{
            "subcategory_parent": "Shoes",
            "subcategory": [
                {
                    "subcategory_id": "840",
                    "subcategory_label": "Casual"
                }
            ]}
        ]} 
 ],
  "prices": [
      {
        "price_label": "",
        "price_currency": "USD",
        "price_wholesale": 30.00,
        "price_retail": 75.00,
        "price_currency_retail": "USD"
      }
  ],
  "colors": [{
        "color_name": "Black",
        "color_code": "1",
        "color_image": "",
        "color_swatch": "/img/uploads/accounts/280561/images/WEST01M1 (1).jpg",
        "minimum": "0"
      }]
  ,
  "images": [
      "/img/uploads/accounts/280561/images/WEST01M1.jpg"
  ]
}, {
  "style_id": "3745126",
  "style_name": "Clarity",
  "style_number": "CLAR01M1",
  "style_identifier": "CLAR01M1||",
  "style_description": "",
  "made_to_order": "True",
  "division": "MEN'S SHOES",
  "division_code": "M1",
  "style_country_origin": "",
  "measurements": "",
  "fabrication": "",
  "fabrication_code": "",
  "silhouette": "",
  "silhouette_code": "",
  "source_of_materials": "",
  "heel_height": "",
  "contains_fur": "",
  "best_seller": "False",
  "minimum": "12",

  "categories": [  
    {
        "category_parent": "Men's",
        "subcategories": [{
            "subcategory_parent": "Shoes",
            "subcategory": [
                {
                    "subcategory_id": "840",
                    "subcategory_label": "Casual"
                }
            ]}
        ]} 
 ],
  "prices": [
      {
        "price_label": "",
        "price_currency": "USD",
        "price_wholesale": 57.50,
        "price_retail": 125.00,
        "price_currency_retail": "USD"
      }
  ],
  "upcs": [
      {
        "sku_color_code": "1",
        "sku_size": "7",
        "upc": "888509010764",
        "inventory_available": "0"
      }, 
      {
        "sku_color_code": "1",
        "sku_size": "7.5",
        "upc": "888509010771",
        "inventory_available": "0"
      }, 
      {
        "sku_color_code": "1",
        "sku_size": "8",
        "upc": "888509010788",
        "inventory_available": "0"
      }, 
      }]
```

I have above Json object in a string variable.

Can somebody tell me how to access the "price_currency" in prices?

```
 JSONObject json = new JSONObject(output);
           String sc = json.get("styles").toString();
```

I got styles using above method,

after than i got style using below code. Style is inside the styles.

```
JSONObject json1 = new JSONObject(sc);
               String sc1 = json1.get("style").toString();
```

Now i want to get "price_currency" in prices? how do i do that?

Comment: I think the Json is incomplete. Please check again.

Comment: When you ask a question and expect people to help you, you need to deliver a correct json format not necceraly a full example but per haps a correct sample.

Answer (score 3):

Your prices is inside an `array`. You have to access the element inside array by index first

```
JSONObject outputJson = new JSONObject(output);
JSONObject style = outputJson.getJsonObject("styles").getJsonArray("style").getJsonObject(0);
JSONObject price = style.getJsonArray("prices").getJsonObject(0);
String currency = price.getString("price_currency");
```

**Edit**

`JSONArray` implements `List<JSONObject>` so you can do:

```
for (JSONObject price : style.getJsonArray("prices")) {
     String currency = price.getString("price_currency");
}
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["style"] not found.

Comment: You have to `getJsonObject("styles")` first. (see edited answer)

Comment: Your JSON is incomplete. Are you getting correct JSON?

Comment: What happens if there are multiple Price segments and if i want to get all price price_currencies?

Comment: Then you have to loop all over the json array: `for (int i = 0; i < style.getJsonArray("prices").length(); i++)`

Comment: It is printing the same currency multiple times. Can you see the edited code in my question?Lets say there are multipe segments in prices,i want to print all currencies. Ex(AUD, USD)

Comment: How can it print same multiple times? Do you print inside the loop?

Comment: In "JSONObject style = outputJson.getJsonObject("styles").getJsonArray("style").getJsonObject(0);" What does this "getJsonObject(0)" part do?

Comment: Get first `JSONObject` from json array. Did you read my edited answer to see how to get all currency?

Comment: Hi, I really appriciate your help. It seems working. I have edited my code. Can you check there's a UPC segment at the bottem. With above code i am not getting UPC segments to the output. Why is that? I only get Prices and sizes to the output

Comment: JSONObject style = outputJson.getJsonObject("styles").getJsonArray("style").getJsonObject(0); this doesnt show UPC. it has only Prices and sizes , why is that

Comment: i think that because of this "getJSONObject(0);"

Comment: Output variable has a long dataset, but when it parsed to style object it has only few segments. why is that

Comment: It can't be. Paste the complete json elsewhere ill look into it

Comment: Hi, Now i know the reason, JSONObject style = outputJson.getJSONObject("styles").getJSONArray("style").getJSONObject(0); You see this "getJSONObject(0)". The reason why i am not getting UPC is "getJSONObject(0) doesnt have UPC. it has only prices and sizes. But getJSONObject(1) has UPC, sizes, prices and all. Likewise there are multiple style segments segments. so how do we run this to multiple style. In your exmples this runs only for getJSONObject0)

Comment: For each doesnt allow JsonObjects in it. we have to use a usual for loop